# I want to display all the cars which are available in a certain time frame entered by the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have made a Query view Model

```
 public class QueryVM
{

    public List<CarVM> CarVMs { get; set; }
```

This contains

```
 public class CarVM
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string RegNumber { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } //From Booking Table
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; } //From Booking Table
```

This is my controller

```
 public ActionResult Searched(DateTime? Start, DateTime? End)
    {
        if (Start.HasValue)
        {
            ViewBag.Start = Start.Value.Date;
        }
        if (End.HasValue)
        {
            ViewBag.End = End.Value.Date;
        }

        QueryVM queryVM = new QueryVM();
        var carList = db.Cars;
        var bookingList = db.Bookings;

        queryVM.CarVMs = new List<CarVM>();
        foreach (var item in carList)
        {
            CarVM cvm = new CarVM();
            cvm.CarID = item.CarID;
            cvm.Make = item.Make;
            cvm.Model = item.Model;
            cvm.Colour = item.Colour;

            queryVM.CarVMs.Add(cvm);
        }

        foreach (var item in bookingList)
        {
            CarVM bvm = new CarVM();
            bvm.StartDate = item.StartDate;
            bvm.EndDate = item.EndDate;
            queryVM.CarVMs.Add(bvm);
        }
        return View(queryVM);
```

first i check if the values have data and then i store them in a viewbag I then populate the Query ViewModel with the information from `db.Cars` and then i populate the `start date` and `end date` from the bookings table and return the ViewModel

This is my code in the view

```
 @{
    if (Model != null && ViewBag.Start != null && ViewBag.End != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.CarVMs.Where(r => ViewBag.Start < r.EndDate && ViewBag.End > r.StartDate))
        {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CarID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Make)
            </td>
```

Over here i want to check the cars which are available between the dates in the viewbag, the `r.EndDate`and `r.StartDate` are current booking dates from the table. I think the issue im getting is that i am getting booking dates from `db.booking` and the car information from `db.Cars` But when i run it i get `null` or `0` but i get the booking dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems messed up. A CarVM is supposed to represent a car, and in this case one would assume it also has a list of date ranges when that car is booked already (not available) but what you're doing is having one CarVM that is the car details and then a bunch of other CarVMs that purely specify the dates the car is booked. Make your life simpler, have a class that has a pair of dates for the start date and end date - let's call it DateRange, have CarVM have a;

```
List<DateRange> BookedDates = new List<DateRange>();
```

Fill this from your db instead of making multiple new CarVM with booked dates in, and then you will have a coherent single data model for the car and its bookings

```
class DateRange{
  public DateTime StartDate{get;set;}
  public DateTime EndDate{get;set;}

  public bool Overlaps(DateTime qStart, DateTime qEnd){
    //a queried date range is only safe if it starts after this
    //range ends or it ends before this range starts.
    //anything else is an overlap
    return !(qStart > EndDate || qEnd < StartDate);
  }
}
```

This means then you can take your list of CarVM and find out which ones are available with:

```
carVMs.Where(c => !c.BookedDates.Any(dr => dr.Overlaps(userChosenStartDate, userChosenEndDate)));
```

"Cars where not any already-booked dates overlaps the dates the user wants the car"

Comment: `public Booking Overlaps(DateTime qStart, DateTime qEnd)
        {
            //a queried date range is only safe if it starts after this
            if (qStart < EndDate){
                qStart = qStart.Date;
            }
            else{
            }
            if (qEnd > StartDate){
                qEnd = qEnd.Date;
            }
            else{
            }
            //range ends or it ends before this range starts.
            //anything else is an overlap
            return !(qStart > EndDate && qEnd < StartDate);`

Comment: in the return it says cannot convert type bool to `sandstrom.models.Booking`

Comment: and how shall i access that in my controller sorry Im trying to understand i am new to MVC

Comment: Sorry, my phone autocorrected bool to book in `public book Overlaps`  - you seem to have guessed it was supposed to be Booking, but it should have been bool

Comment: how would i use that in the controller?

Comment: I already gave (an example) code for using it in the view, and most of my answer is aimed at resolving the error the Controller makes in pulling bookings out of the db and making a new carVM (when I'm saying it should be a new DateRange on an existing carVM) so it should be fairly obvious what to replace in the controller? (hint: the second loop)